# Evaluation of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}n^2}{n^3+1}$

Tags: integration, closed-form, frobenius-method

I have accrossed this sum :$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}n^2}{n^3+1}$ in my textbook , However i have tried to evaluate it using Frobenius method and also the standard sum  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}=\log 2$ , But i didn't suceeded to get the same closed form which it assumed by Wolfram alpha [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D+%5Cfrac%7B(-1)%5E%7Bn%2B1%7Dn%5E2%7D%7Bn%5E3%2B1%7D) using hyperbolic function, then any way for evaluation ?